# SQL Server 2012 RC installation failing

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to test out the new `SS 2012 RC`, but I'm having problems with the installation.

My installation stops a ways in saying that the resource needed cannot be found. I'm using the ISO from MSDN and mounting it using MagicDisc. I browse to the location of the missing resource (`vs_setup.msi`) on the disc and it says that the `vs_setup.msi file is not valid for VS 2010 Ultimate`. I tried both vs_setup.msi's on the installation iso and both said they weren't valid. Any ideas on what I am doing incorrectly?

I do have VS2010 Ultimate already installed.

The dialogue specifically says:

`The feature you are trying to use is on a network resource that is unavailable.`

It tried to default to this directory, but the directory doesn't exist on my machine:

`C:\Users\[UserID]\AppData\Local\Temp\30319.01\1033\VS_VSTS\`

Browsing to the v`s_setup.msi` in `E:\1033_ENU_LP\redist\VisualStudioShell\VSIntSetup` and in `E:\1033_ENU_LP\redist\VisualStudioShell\VSSetup` doesn't work either.

Anyone have any suggestions for what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Hi Igor, did you comment on this? I see your name listed but no comment? Or was it you who highlighted those items? If so, thanks! It makes it more readable!

Comment: Apply SP1 to your VS 2010 installation prior to trying to install SQL 2012 RC0.

Answer (score 2):

Download the Visual Studio 2010 ISO (Ultimate, in your case).

Extract it to a folder and *use that folder path* when prompted for vs_setup.msi.

Answer (score 1):

Can I offer the suggestion of instead of mounting using MagicDisc to mount the ISO try unzipping the contents of the ISO using [7Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/). Once extracted just run the set up from within the extracted folder.

This was my install method and worked fine. Hope it helps.